If $P$ is an indecomposable projective module over a ring with unity $R$, can $P/rP$ also be an indecomposable module over $R$?
Let $P$ be a non-zero projective module over a ring with unity $R$, and let $r$ be the Jacobson radical of $R$.
If $P/rP$ is indecomposable, then $P$ is indecomposable. This is because if $P = P_1 \oplus P_2$ where $P_1 \neq 0$ and $P_2 \neq 0$, then
$$
P/rP = (P_1 \oplus P_2)/(r(P_1 \oplus P_2)) = (P_1 \oplus P_2)/(rP_1 \oplus rP_2) \simeq (P_1/rP_1) \oplus (P_2/rP_2).
$$
Since $P_1 \neq 0$ and $P_2 \neq 0$, $P_1/rP_1 \neq 0$ and $P_2/rP_2 \neq 0$, which implies that $P/rP$ is not indecomposable.
What about the other way around? That is, if $P$ is indecomposable, can we conclude that $P/rP$ is also indecomposable?

Are you assuming $P$ is finitely generated? Else I don't see why $P_i / rP_i \neq 0$.

@Maximilien Mackie   I do not assume that $P$ is finitely generated because any non-zero projective module has a maximal submodule, and $rP = \text{Rad} P$, which is the intersection of all maximal submodules. Therefore, $rP$ must be a proper submodule of $P$ when $P$ is non-zero.

I'm absolutely sure that there must be easier counterexamples, but it occurred to me that the ring in this answer to another recent question of yours gives an example.
In
Gerasimov, V. N.; Sakhaev, I. I., A counterexample to two hypotheses on projective and flat modules, Sib. Math. J. 25, 855-859 (1984); translation from Sib. Mat. Zh. 25, No. 6(148), 31-35 (1984). ZBL0588.16017,
a ring $R_\Sigma$ is constructed, which is further studied in
Dubrovin, Nikolay; Příhoda, Pavel; Puninski, Gena, Projective modules over the Gerasimov-Sakhaev counterexample., J. Algebra 319, No. 8, 3259-3279 (2008). ZBL1194.16001.
This ring has precisely two maximal right ideals, and so $R_\Sigma/\operatorname{rad}R_\Sigma$ is the direct sum of two simple modules, and in particular is not indecomposable.
However, by Corollary 6.4 in Dubrovin, Příhoda and Puninski's paper, $R_\Sigma$ has no nontrivial idempotents, and so $R_\Sigma$ is indecomposable as a right module.
